# /etc/rc0.d script not allowed to finish

Tags: scripts, shutdown

I have a script that I've written that needs to run during shutdown which brings down my vagrant instance. The script runs without issue, and I echo output to stdout (and to a file) of the process.

The script outputs the following:

```
Shutting down vagrant
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
Vagrant shut down
```

However, when this runs from a computer shutdown (rc0) or reboot (rc6), the terminal logs the first two lines and then moves on without shutting down vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

Add a call to the [wait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait_%28command%29) command after you halt `vagrant`. Something like this,

```
# Shutdown vagrant
vagrant halt
# wait for the halt
wait
```

Comment: Thanks Elliot. The issue was actually completely on my end. The rc calls are not asynchronous. I was echoing STDERR to a file. The vagrant halt command threw an exception as it couldn't read the $HOME variable. The exception was written to STDOUT. Removing the redirects, setting a dummy $HOME variable looks like it did the trick. Waiting to gain reputation points to post the answer.

Comment: @eggmatters When you program any issues are **very nearly always** completely on your end.

Comment: Yes, that is one of my programming axioms